# Cannot use relative image path in Avalonia XAML

Tags: .net-core, avaloniaui

So I switched from WPF to Avalonia for my application's cross-platform usage. WPF supports relative path for image. But when I switch to Avalonia, set the Window's background to an ImageBrush with a source of a relative path of an Image (something like `Images/Background.png`), it outputs:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The resource Images/Background.png could not be found.'
```

I first thought because the string cannot be converted to `IBitmap` interface, but then I realised that I was wrong when I gave it the absolute path (something like `C:\Users\username\source\repos\MySolution\MyProject\Images\Background.png`).
How can I solve this problem?

Edit: `Images/Background.png` is copied to output directory, and I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add all your assets to a tag inside your `.csproj` file, so that Avalonia can find them. A relative path is sufficient. If your `.csproj` is inside your applications' root folder, then you would need to add the following property inside your `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AvaloniaResource Include="Images\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

#### Recommendation

When you create a Avalonia Project from the template inside Visual Studio, then the folder `Assets` will automatically be included, e.g. this will be in your `.csproj` by default:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AvaloniaResource Include="Assets\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I personally think it is better practice to just create an `Images` folder inside the `Assets` directory and place your images there. That way they are automatically included without you needing to modify your `.csproj` (assuming you used the official templates).